# How to know where var_dump function is used?

Tags: php, orm, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying out Laravel 4. When using the ORM to create a new user account, this is echoed to the page:

```
array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#103 (1) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(98)
    }
}
```

I have absolutely no idea where the var_dump statement is. I've gone through the entire source code trying to find out where this is echoed, but couldn't find anything.

What could cause this ? How can I know where the var_dump statement is ?

Comment: `die()` statements placed strategically throughout the main dispatch loop until you find where it is. Binary sort the problem. Or install a debugger.

Comment: Considering that Laravel 4 is not yet stable, you should never rule out the possibility that bugs exist. Perhaps you could show us your route/controller/model file(s)?

Comment: Found the issue. A debug statement left by mistake I guess. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: @conradk - if you have solved the issue - please mark it as such

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is displaying the data types, you will want to search for: `var_dump`

Comment: I have, didn't find any.

Comment: It can be also command `dd`

Answer (score 2):

That's not a `print_r`, that's a `var_dump`. Try searching your source files for that.

But it should be in the same location in the source as the content surrounding it.

Comment: I have as well. Couldn't find any.

Answer (score 0):

Open the project on Netbeans, right click on Source folder and click on find... Search for var_dump(

You will get it.

Easy?